# Symfony return JsonResponse from service

Tags: php, web-services, fosrestbundle, symfony-3.3

I have a controller Returning a JsonResponse from mobile application, for each action i must verify that user is connected using a token. I want to delegate this action in a service authentification.

```
    $user = $this->em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('email' => $username));
    if (!$user) {
        return new JsonResponse('User not found', 501);
    }
    $session = $this->em->getRepository('UserBundle:Session')->findOneBy(array('user' => $user->getId(), 'token' => $token));
    if(!$session){
        return new JsonResponse('Session not found', 501);
    }
    return true;
```

here everything work well but in my controller i have to this test to verify the result.

```
    if($result instanceof JsonResponse){
        return $result;
    }
    ...
```

Can i return the JsonResponse directly from service and stop execution in the controller or is there any bests solutions to do this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that noone answered this question, I would be curious too about it, however I was told that this is not the way to go. The explanation was if you want to change the response type from json to something else you will have to refactor many classes (including services), but if you create the response in the controller, you can just change it there.